# Instance of a type declared within package is opaque after compilation for debug

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle11gr2

So i have a type declaration within package as :

```
TYPE lt_sometpye IS TABLE OF gt_sometype INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
```

and am facing 2 problems :

- 1st i can create a type in database, not in package, which looks like

  `TYPE lt_sometpye IS TABLE OF gt_sometype;`

but it cant be indexed with `INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER` which is a requirement.

- 2nd alternatively i declared same type in the package with index. After compiling it, instances of it are opaque when debugging.

In both cases `gt_sometype` is also compiled for debug.

How can i make the instance of such type display actual data while being watched during debug?

Comment: Associative array (`index by`) is PL/SQL-only collection type. SQL (at least up to 11g) doesn't support it.

Comment: thx, i updated tags, adding this is for 11g2

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused what youre problem is.  Why not this?

```
create or replace type matt_typ AS OBJECT ( a number );

declare
  type plsql_type_t is table of matt_typ INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  l_tab plsql_type_t;
begin
  l_tab (l_tab.count+1) := new matt_typ(5);
end;
```

Sorry, I know that's not an answer, but the SQL wouldn't fit in a comment.

Comment: This is similar to what i described in my 2nd problem, so for plsql_type_t i cannot see property values but am getting opaque.